# How to replace the characters in the next 3 lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, replace

How can I replace 404 to 403 only in the 2nd if block, my cursor is now at row 45.

```
 41         if( error.response.status === 404 ) {
 42             router.replace('/404')
 43         }
 44
 45         if( error.response.status === 404 ) {
 46             router.replace('/404')
 47         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cursor is at line 45, you can do this, `,+2` means including current line and next 2 lines

```
:,+2s/404/403/g
```

If your cursor is at any position, you can do this

```
:45,+2s/404/403/g
```